# Content-neutral video organizer/manager?

Tags: windows, video, file-management

I have thousands of videos that aren't TV or movie related that I need to be able to organize by file size and ideally video length as well. I need to be able to see previews of the video in the organization view, and if possible the ability to easily play videos inside the program.

I've been searching off and on for over a year and have never found one that isn't movie or television focused.

Just to clear things up: There's no meta data, the titles of the videos are irrelevant, and no database will have any information on any of the videos.